# Bootstrap Hidden Element Requires Place

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have included a navbar at the bottom of the page.
But The `notification bar` element (look comment - it is the `div` element with the id `warning`.

The `notification bar` can change It's visibility. But when the visibility is 'collapsed' the div is still taking up all space.

**My code:**

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">

    <!-- notification bar element can change visibility -->
    <div class="row"  id="warning" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <h2>Bottom Notification</h2>
        <small>Timestamp</small>
        <h3>This is a message.</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- -->

    <!-- element is static - can't change visibility -->
    <div class="container row">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-left">© 2016 - xxxx</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I change it so that the div is not taking any space away when the visibility is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `visibility` you can use `hide` class and toggle it

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <!-- notification bar element can change visibility -->
    <div class="row hide"  id="warning">
        <h2>Bottom Notification</h2>
        <small>Timestamp</small>
        <h3>This is a message.</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
   <!-- element is static - can't change visibility -->
    <div class="container row">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-left">© 2016 - xxxx</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice - it is working :) - will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The `visibility` could be seen as an opacity... so the element is there but with opacity zero, when hidden.

If you don't want it to use the place, rather use `display`:

```
<div class="row"  id="warning" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `style="visibility: hidden;"` to `style="display: none;`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">

    <!-- notification bar element can change visibility -->
    <div class="row"  id="warning" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Bottom Notification</h2>
        <small>Timestamp</small>
        <h3>This is a message.</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- -->

   <!-- element is static - can't change visibility -->
    <div class="container row">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-left">© 2016 - xxxx
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
display: none
```

instead of

```
visibility: hidden
```

The difference is well explained on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Answer (score 0):

that's the whole idea of visibility: hidden;, it keeps the space even it hides the element. But in display:none will leave the space .